# Browse files on VLC SFTP

Tags: vlc-media-player, sftp

I can open a folder or file over SFTP on VLC via `Media` > `Open Network Stream` > `Play`. If I open the file it plays perfectly, but if I open a folder it plays the first file found recursively.

Is it possible to open a folder and navigate through the file system to find the file I'd like to play?

So if I open `sftp://pi@localhost:2222//media/hdd/TV Shows/Friends/Season 1/friends_s01e01.mkv` it should play the file, but if I open `sftp://pi@localhost:2222//media/hdd/TV Shows/Friends/Season 1/` it should open a file explorer type interface.

Comment: on VLC for Android - it works

Comment: @laplasz yes - and I'm currently wondering why this feature is only implemented only on Android

Comment: And I still wonder the same thing...